# How to use Reduce with inverse trigonometric functions?

Tags: differential-equations

```
Clear["`."]
rm = 1; al = Pi/6; csal = Cos[al];
DSolve[{rm ph'[s] == Sin[si[s]] Tan[si[s]]^2 csal, 
  rm si'[s] == -Sin[ph[s]] Sin[si[s]]^2}, {ph, si}, s]
```

How to Reduce in order to obtain the solution in a reasonable time?

EDIT1:

These are differential equations of straight (geodesic) and asymptotic lines on a one sheeted hyperboloid of revolution. Angles (si,ph) are angles made by meridians to the geodesic and symmetry axis respectively. A numerical solution looks like:

[image: 1 sht Hyperbld]

I expected that the closed form solution to be extremely simple just as the shell shape is. But it turns out so hard to *Reduce* it !

EDIT2:

Obtained the following relations analytically:

$$  ph[s]=\phi,si[s]=\psi\,;$$

$$ \frac{1}{\sin^2\psi}=\frac{1}{\sin^2\alpha}+\frac{s^2}{rm^2} \,;$$

$$\tan \phi= \tan \alpha \sin \psi\cdot \frac{s}{rm}\,;$$

Comment: what is reasonable? I could calculate within 15s

Comment: @morbo Could you demonstrate your solution? In version 11.2 the system returned the input unevaluated.

Comment: Mathematica **12.1** gives a solution within 20s.

Comment: Yes mma 12 and above gives a huge result in short order,

Comment: @morbo: Can you please check my EDIT2 analytical results?  I wished to avoid these laborious calculations by employing *Mathematica* for the same purpose.

Comment: @Narasimham I find your question very interesting and upvoted it earlier nonetheless I guess you haven't demonstrated the problem clearly, where from the equations, what you expect,  why `rm=1, al=Pi/6` etc. It seems the solutions can be given in terms of elliptic functions and `Mathematica` cannot find them in an appropriately simple way, even though there must be some neat approach. I will try tomorrow to work on it and in any case remind me of your problem.   Certainly it deserves more attention.

Comment: @Narasimham The problem is that `Mathematica` fails to avoid laborious claculations in many cases if there are elliptic functions involved, instead one has to change variables or do something  smarter to elucidate the problem.

Comment: @Artes.Even in relatively simple trig function manipulations as here ( I can include the derivation for EDIT2 result if there is interest ), *Mathematica* does not simplify to supply a neater output.. is indeed a problem.

Answer (score 1):

With "Weierstrass" -substitution `si[s]=2 ArcTan[us[s],ph[s]=2 ArcTan[up[s],`

you might find simple equation and a fast solution:

```
ode = {rm ph'[s] == Sin[si[s]] Tan[si[s]]^2 csal,rm si'[s] == -Sin[ph[s]] Sin[
     si[s]]^2} /. {ph -> (2 ArcTan[up[#]] &),si -> (2 ArcTan[us[#]] &)} // TrigExpand // FullSimplify
(*{(2 Derivative[1][up][s])/(1 + up[s]^2) == (4 Sqrt[3] us[s]^3)/((-1 + us[s]^2)^2 (1 + us[s]^2)),
(4 up[s] us[s]^2)/((1 + up[s]^2) (1 + us[s]^2)) +Derivative[1][us][s] == 0}*)
```

These equations are solved in 1.2s:

```
DSolve[ode, {up, us}, s] // FullSimplify
(* {us->…, up->... *)  


{{us -> Function[{s}, -((\[Sqrt](-1 + csal - 2 csal C[1] + 
       csal InverseFunction[-(((2 (1 + 2 csal C[1]) #1 (1 + 
                2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)))/(1 + 
                csal (-1 + 2 C[1])) + (I (1 + 
                csal (-1 + 4 C[1])) (EllipticE[
                I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))] -
                 EllipticF[
                I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(
                2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))]) Sqrt[
                1 + (csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) #1^2)/(
                1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1]))] Sqrt[(
                2 + 4 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2))/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])])/((-1 + 2 C[1]) Sqrt[(
                csal C[1])/(1 + 2 csal C[1])]) - 
                2 #1 (1 + 
                csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)))/(2 csal (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]) Sqrt[-1 - 2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)]
                 Sqrt[-1 - csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)])) &][-((
           4 s)/(csal rm)) + C[2]]^2 - 
       2 csal C[
        1] InverseFunction[-(((2 (1 + 2 csal C[1]) #1 (1 + 
                2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)))/(1 + 
                csal (-1 + 2 C[1])) + (I (1 +         csal (-1 + 4 C[1])) (EllipticE[
                I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))] -
                 EllipticF[
                I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(
                2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))]) Sqrt[
                1 + (csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) #1^2)/(
                1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1]))] Sqrt[(
                2 + 4 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2))/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])])/((-1 + 2 C[1]) Sqrt[(
                csal C[1])/(1 + 2 csal C[1])]) - 
                2 #1 (1 + 
                csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)))/(2 csal (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]) Sqrt[-1 - 2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)]
                 Sqrt[-1 - csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)])) &][-((
           4 s)/(csal rm)) + C[2]]^2))/(\[Sqrt](-1 - 
       2 csal C[1] - 
       2 csal C[
        1] InverseFunction[-(((2 (1 + 2 csal C[1]) #1 (1 + 
                2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)))/(1 + 
                csal (-1 + 2 C[1])) + (I (1 + 
                csal (-1 + 4 C[1])) (EllipticE[
                I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))] -
                 EllipticF[
                I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(
                2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))]) Sqrt[
                1 + (csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) #1^2)/(
                1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1]))] Sqrt[(
                2 + 4 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2))/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])])/((-1 + 2 C[1]) Sqrt[(
                csal C[1])/(1 + 2 csal C[1])]) - 
                2 #1 (1 + 
                csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)))/(2 csal (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]) Sqrt[-1 - 2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)]
                 Sqrt[-1 - csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)])) &][-((
           4 s)/(csal rm)) + C[2]]^2)))], 
up -> Function[{s}, 
InverseFunction[-(((
        2 (1 + 2 csal C[1]) #1 (1 + 2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)))/(
        1 + csal (-1 + 
            2 C[1])) + (I (1 + 
             csal (-1 + 4 C[1])) (EllipticE[
              I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))] -
              EllipticF[
              I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(
              2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))]) Sqrt[
           1 + (csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) #1^2)/(1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1]))]
            Sqrt[(2 + 4 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2))/(
           1 + 2 csal C[1])])/((-1 + 2 C[1]) Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
           1 + 2 csal C[1])]) - 
        2 #1 (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)))/(2 csal (1 + 
          2 csal C[1]) Sqrt[-1 - 2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)]
         Sqrt[-1 - csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)])) &][-((4 s)/(
   csal rm)) + C[2]]]}, {us -> 
Function[{s}, (\[Sqrt](-1 + csal - 2 csal C[1] + 
     csal InverseFunction[-(((2 (1 + 2 csal C[1]) #1 (1 + 
                2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)))/(1 + 
                csal (-1 + 2 C[1])) + (I (1 + 
                csal (-1 + 4 C[1])) (EllipticE[
                I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))] -
                 EllipticF[
                I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(
                2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))]) Sqrt[
                1 + (csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) #1^2)/(
                1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1]))] Sqrt[(
                2 + 4 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2))/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])])/((-1 + 2 C[1]) Sqrt[(
                csal C[1])/(1 + 2 csal C[1])]) - 
              2 #1 (1 + 
                csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)))/(2 csal (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]) Sqrt[-1 - 2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)]
               Sqrt[-1 - csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)])) &][(
        4 s)/(csal rm) + C[2]]^2 - 
     2 csal C[
      1] InverseFunction[-(((2 (1 + 2 csal C[1]) #1 (1 + 
                2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)))/(1 + 
                csal (-1 + 2 C[1])) + (I (1 + 
                csal (-1 + 4 C[1])) (EllipticE[
                I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))] -
                 EllipticF[
                I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(
                2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))]) Sqrt[
                1 + (csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) #1^2)/(
                1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1]))] Sqrt[(
                2 + 4 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2))/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])])/((-1 + 2 C[1]) Sqrt[(
                csal C[1])/(1 + 2 csal C[1])]) - 

              2 #1 (1 + 
                csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)))/(2 csal (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]) Sqrt[-1 - 2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)]
               Sqrt[-1 - csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)])) &][(
        4 s)/(csal rm) + C[2]]^2))/(\[Sqrt](-1 - 2 csal C[1] - 
     2 csal C[
      1] InverseFunction[-(((2 (1 + 2 csal C[1]) #1 (1 + 
                2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)))/(1 + 
                csal (-1 + 2 C[1])) + (I (1 + 
                csal (-1 + 4 C[1])) (EllipticE[
                I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))] -
                 EllipticF[
                I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(
                2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))]) Sqrt[
                1 + (csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) #1^2)/(
                1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1]))] Sqrt[(
                2 + 4 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2))/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])])/((-1 + 2 C[1]) Sqrt[(
                csal C[1])/(1 + 2 csal C[1])]) - 
              2 #1 (1 + 
                csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)))/(2 csal (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]) Sqrt[-1 - 2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)]
               Sqrt[-1 - csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)])) &][(
        4 s)/(csal rm) + C[2]]^2))], 
up -> Function[{s}, 
InverseFunction[-(((
        2 (1 + 2 csal C[1]) #1 (1 + 2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)))/(
        1 + csal (-1 + 
            2 C[1])) + (I (1 + 
             csal (-1 + 4 C[1])) (EllipticE[
              I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))] -
              EllipticF[
              I ArcSinh[
                Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
                1 + 2 csal C[1])] #1], ((-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + 
                2 csal C[1]))/(
              2 C[1] (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1])))]) Sqrt[
           1 + (csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) #1^2)/(1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1]))]
            Sqrt[(2 + 4 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2))/(
           1 + 2 csal C[1])])/((-1 + 2 C[1]) Sqrt[(csal C[1])/(
           1 + 2 csal C[1])]) - 
        2 #1 (1 + csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)))/(2 csal (1 + 
          2 csal C[1]) Sqrt[-1 - 2 csal C[1] (1 + #1^2)]
         Sqrt[-1 - csal (-1 + 2 C[1]) (1 + #1^2)])) &][(4 s)/(
  csal rm) + C[2]]]}}
```

Comment: Why don't  you provide these solutions?   In version 11.2 no solutions were obtained with your substiution.

Comment: @Artes The result is a huge expression. What's the problem with 11.2?

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: How does the result simplify with initial condition $ ph=0, si= \alpha $?

Comment: @Narasimham Look at the transformation rules: For example `ph]0]==0` implies `up[0]=Tan[0/2]=0`